# How to deniably send a value

Tags: plausible-deniability

Alice has a single bit of information, `b`, that she wants to send to Bob (over an unalterable but possibly-monitored channel) but  in such a way that without the cooperation of Bob she *cannot* prove to anyone else (Eve) besides Bob after-the-fact that she sent `b` and not `1-b`.

Is this possible? I am thinking perhaps not, because in any protocol Eve could step through the inputs Alice receives from Bob with both `b` and `1-b`, and check which one of those the output she sends back to Bob matches. Even if the protocol is non-deterministic Alice could record the random values for Eve - but perhaps there is some way in which the random values could be set up to be trivially spoofed to indicate the other value to Eve after-the-fact (and hence Eve would not be able to trust Alice)?

Comment: Would a simple [one-time-pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) suffice? Unless both bob & alice would confirm they were both using the same key, it will always be possible for bob to easily claim that a different key was used resulting in another valid message.

Comment: @DaanBakker That would require Eve to trust at least one of Alice and Bob, otherwise they can agree to lie to Eve.

Comment: (Moreover, Eve obviously cannot trust Alice; otherwise Alice can always prove to Eve that $b$ was sent, just by telling her "$b$ was sent".)

Comment: This task looks like it would be quite tricky to define in the first place, even before going into whether it is achievable.

Comment: I think _entrusted undenieable signatures_ should do the trick here. Basically you have a signature that can only be verified with the consent of a trusted third party. In this case it (maybe) should be possible to establish Bob as such. But I honestly have no clue about them except what is described in Schneier's Applied Cryptography, so I can't give a full answer. And even worse I can't find an online version of the original paper: *"An Entrusted Undenieable Signature"* by Park, Lee, Won in 1995.

Comment: So if I understand this question correctly: Eve intercepts the message from Alice to Bob but cannot read it. Only with the cooperation of *both* Alice and Bob and can the message be read and verified? So Bob by himself cannot prove what message was sent either?

Comment: @DaanBakker re. one time pad - how exactly do you propose to transfer the one-time pad between the two of them? You've just moved the problem from transferring one bit of information (`b`) to transferring another bit of information (the one time pad). I don't see how that helps you.

Comment: @DaanBakker - re. understanding. In this case Bob being able to prove what message was sent is not a problem. It's Alice being able to prove to a third party (who has recorded all messages between Alice <-> Bob) what message was sent without Bob's consent that's the problem. I think you have it backwards.

Comment: @SEJPM - Interesting, but I don't see how this would help? I shall certainly take a look, though.

Comment: @TLW re. onetime pad - The way a one-time pad helps you is that you only need a direct, secure communication channel occasionally (e.g. Alice & Bob meeting in person). If there is no private pre-shared information but everything is out in the open (e.g. public keys) then Alice can always show everything she used to generate the message. With any ambiguity Bob won't be able to decrypt the message either.

Comment: in theory it's impossible, but in practice, all that's needed is to prevent alice or bob from knowing the keys and randomness. no one can recall what they never knew to begin with.

Comment: @dandavis : ​ ​ ​ If indistinguishability obfuscation is theoretically possible then what the OP is asking about is theoretically possible. ​ (See my answer.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

By [this paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454.pdf#page=5), indistinguishability obfuscation is enough for that.

Comment: As it stands this is pretty much a link-only answer. Would you mind expanding it a bit to give people an idea on how this works/ how this notion does what the OP needs?

Comment: I'd like an elaboration, but this certainly seems to be exactly what I'm after: "In deniable encryption, a sender who is forced to reveal to an adversary both her
message and the randomness she used for encrypting it should be able to convincingly provide “fake”
randomness that can explain any alternative message that she would like to pretend that she sent. We
resolve this question by giving the first construction of deniable encryption that does not require any
pre-planning by the party that must later issue a denial."

Comment: @TLW That seems impossible to me. If the exact same ciphertext can be created by using 2 different messages how will the receiver ever be able to differentiate between the two (without pre-shared information)?

Comment: I don't know - that's a direct quote from the paper, and I'm still reading through it. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I've read through the paper, and it seems that in all cases extra "private" randomness is required provided by a trusted third party.

Comment: @DaanBakker : ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ The "simplest" way would be if for each possible ciphertext c, the probabilities of ​ [encrypting 0 gives c] , [encrypting 1 gives c] ​ differ by at least an exponential factor and the receiver can tell which case is more likely. ​ ​ ​ (I don't know if they actually achieve that or instead get an exponentially-small error probability in a different way.) ​ ​ ​ See section 4, "Our Deniable Encryption System". ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​